# Issue with Selectionchanged event for a listbox in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have a listbox with several items . And the selection changed event has been mapped to a function. But everytime i select a listbox item, event is getting triggered twice. As result i am getting the selected index as -1 on the second round .

anyone knows the reason for this behaviour?

XAML code

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource productTemplate}" Name="lstItems" SelectionChanged="ShowProductDetails">
```

C# code

```
private void ShowProductDetails(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Item item = lstItems.SelectedItem as Item;
    int index = lstItems.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't sounds right. You are going to have to show us the relevant bits of your code.

Comment: That sounds like something is deselecting the listbox item right after its being selected - show us the code and we might be able to assist

Comment: You're getting a -1 because there is no item selected. This is most likely because your ListBox is refreshed or regenerated, or something else which basically resets your ListBox.

Comment: Is there any way which we can avoid that refresh action?

Comment: We need to figure out why your `selectedindex` is being reset. If you could put in some code to show how you generate your items, or if you have a `Loaded` event handler doing something to the ListBox, some relevant code might help.

Comment: thanks for the help guys . I am reloading the listbox on selecting the listbox item. And thats why the event gets triggerred for the second time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A selection changed event happens everytime the selection is changed (either from user input or not)

When you reload the listbox the selection changes (most likely to -1)

this code below checks to ensure that a user has selected something (an item with a valid index i.e. Not -1) then runs the code.

```
    private void ShowProductDetails(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(lstItems.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Item item = lstItems.SelectedItem as Item;
            int index = lstItems.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
```